# Are etymology claims off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I read the faq :

> it's for researching the evidence
>   behind the claims you hear or read.

So why was my question, about a rumor I heard [about the etymology of a word](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5035/where-did-the-french-word-canif-small-knife-came-from), closed ?

The point of this site really isn't clear. I propose [one rumor](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4923/was-this-quote-about-unruly-kids-written-by-an-assyrian) and get tons of researched answers, I propose another and it's off topic.

I'm lost here, please help.

Comment: In case you're wondering, [Wikipedia.fr](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canif) says, 'Le mot français canif et le mot anglais knife ("couteau") sont tous deux dérivés du mot d'ancien français "canivet".' That sounds plausible to me because I find it more likely that an English word would derive from the French one than vice versa: especially an old/common word like knife.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is [the crux of your question really about skepticism?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223/what-sort-of-skepticism-is-on-topic)

As Mark Rogers says in reply to the question above:

> No, I believe that every
>   question-asker must make some attempt
>   to apply Skepticism in the content of
>   their question.

Are you really skeptical that canif comes from knife? or are you just wanting to get the facts?

As an example, a question like:

> "Do cats purr when they are happy?"
>   because I heard someone say they do it
>   because they are going to sleep.

Is not a good question because essentially you are just fact checking, your question is really 'Why do cats purr?'.

**This site is not the equivalent of a 'How does everything and anything work' site.**

Your question is actually straight forward and can be written as 'What is the etymology of the French word canif?', which doesn't belong on this site.

Comment: He was asking a Boolean question though: not "how", but "whether". Sceptics questions usually are Boolean: "Is 'X' true?"

Comment: @ChrisW - But is there really a skeptical claim behind his question or does a simple fact checking give him the answer? Is his question not really 'What is the etymology...' instead of 'I heard... '. Just hearing about something, does that make it a skeptical claim? I _heard_ cats purr when they are going to sleep. Is that a good question for this site or does it belong more on a site about pets or cats?

Comment: It's borderline IMO. I'd be inclined to close it, but I'm not sure why: not because it's "how and/or why does this work?" kind of science question (it isn't). It has the right format or syntax for a Sceptics question; I guess it's the 'notability' of the claim that's missing; and the fact that it *isn't* a science question and therefore can't be 'pseudoscience'.

Comment: @ChrisW: You say it *isn't* a science question. I'm interested why etymology isn't a science. (I don't know either way. No doubt Rutherford would dismiss it as stamp-collecting.)

Comment: @Odd - Maybe it is 'science', in the sense of 'systematic knowledge'. When I was at school there were three categories of class, three streams of teaching, and students were expected to specialize into learning one: there was science (including maths, physics, biology, and chemistry); modern languages (including english); and history (including ancient languages). According to *that* classification, etymology isn't a science. If it *is* a science then, what isn't? Perhaps any questions with a yes/no, true/false answer could be called 'science': if you equate 'science' with 'what ever is true'.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to distract with a "definition of science" question. I note that history questions are clearly acceptable. In a way, etymology is a type of history. I'm still trying to elucidate what makes etymology on- or off-topic.

Comment: @Odd - You could ask the members of the community who voted to close it. A comment says it would have been better on a sister site i.e. http://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

[This is not an answer to your main question. This question was closed by the community, not by a moderator, and I am watching this question to learn what the community wants.]

However, I will not that, had the question remained, I would have asked you to provide some [references to support notability](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) - that is, evidence that the claim is common or has been made by someone important.

I think there are two reasons for this:

- If I am going to spend time researching an answer, I want to know that it will be worth it - that the claim is something that people believe, not just the result of a drunken discussion in a bar that will be forgotten in a couple of days.
- When it comes to weird claims, I want to help rid the world of the false ones and, even better, convince people the true ones are actually true. What I don't want is to do is reward people with reputation points for making up new weird claims on the spot.

I don't think I am alone in the community on this.

Fortunately, providing such evidence is normally a simple Google search away.

Your first 2800 BC rumor was also insufficiently notable, but within 45 minutes of you posting it, someone had posted in the comments a reference to the claim being made by a notable person, and I had edited the title to bring it back to the claim in that reference, so in that case, the community had your back!

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to understand.